# How to create a heatmap with month outlines in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to create a heat map, like the github contribution chart, but with outlines for the months. The result should look like this:

[image]

While I see no problem in render the daily based data, I have no idea how to add the month outline.

Comment: I'm assuming your current chart looks like that minus the monthly divisions?  Unsure of what your highcharts setup looks like - but have you looked at column borders: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.borderWidth. Another idea, maybe look at the raw HTML code and see if there is a way for you to hardcode in the borders with a script or css. Although if github does it, I'm sure there is a way to do it within the highcharts api

Comment: The problem is that the border needs to be set per cell. But the the only thing that can be set for a data cell is the color. There is an example on how to do this with d3: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318 .So my idea is to use the highcharts drawing API to draw the lines by myself to the chart.

Comment: You can use heatmap and then add custom lines (line borders) by [Renderer path](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.path)